# Whats the simpelst way to determine the version of SAML on a Active Directory Federation Serivce?

Tags: saml, saml-2.0, adfs, windows-server-2012-r2, adfs3.0

When I am connected on a Windows Server (for example 2012R2) on which ADFS is installed, SSO with Microsoft365 is working well. What would be fastes way to determine, which SAML Version, 1.0 or 2.0, is used in this envrionment SSO?

Comment: Adfs supports saml2 and saml1.1 since adfs2 which was there like 10 years ago.

Comment: Thanks but is there a simple way to check this setting if its saml2 or saml1.1 active?

Comment: Yes, you have to read the metadata. It's an xml that contains all active services and their endpoints. Adfs has one metadata for all services, including saml2 saml1 active passive etc.

Comment: Metadata is at https://adfs../federationmetadata/2007-06/federationmetadata.xml

Comment: Thanks, yes, i was able to open the XML and checked this also before. But on which node or value am I able to determine if my SSO works by default with "SAML 2.0" or only "SAML 1.1"? When I make ctrl F inside the Metadata XML, i find both SAML types (1.1 and 2.0) on different lines.

Comment: Your app has to be registered in adfs as a relying party in order to be able to use adfs. This is done manually by the adfs administrator. You just ask the admin then. If your app is not registered, sso will never work.

Comment: My app, in our case its Microsoft 365, its already registered as relying party to use adfs. The SSO works well. Also if I open the properties of the Relying Party Trust I am able to read the XML metadata url. If I open the metadata URL and search inside with Ctrl F for "SAML", i find on some lines SAML:2.0 but also some SAML:1.0 inside. How can I know, which one is used as default?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229097/discussion-between-baku-bakar-and-wiktor-zychla).

Comment: If your app is registered and ADFS has both services then you can use both.